# Emitting warnings from Template Haskell splices

Tags: haskell, ghc, template-haskell

I know that I can cause a compile-time error by calling `fail` from a splice, but is it possible to only generate a warning? In particular I would like it to be possible to turn this warning into an error when compiling with `-Werror`.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is this:

```
todo :: Q Exp
todo = do
    -- emit warning somehow

    loc <- location
    let message = ... -- generate message based on loc
    [| error $(litE (stringL message)) |]
```

The idea is to use this instead of `undefined` while coding, but make sure it doesn't sneak its way into production code by compiling with `-Werror`.

```
myFunc x | isSimpleCase x = 42
         | otherwise = $todo
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the function I was after was the Template Haskell function `report`. Its type signature was in the documentation, but I had to read the source code to figure out what it did. The TH documentation sure could use some improvements.

Anyway, my `todo` placeholder is now working perfectly, and I'll put something up on Hackage soon if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible naively from TH, but it is a really cool idea.

One way to implement it would be via bindings to the [GHC-API](http://lambda.haskell.org/hp-tmp/docs/2011.2.0.0/ghc-api/index.html) warning and [debug output](http://lambda.haskell.org/hp-tmp/docs/2011.2.0.0/ghc-api/Panic.html) or [error](http://lambda.haskell.org/hp-tmp/docs/2011.2.0.0/ghc-api/ErrUtils.html) functions.

E.g. to pretend to be GHC,

```
import Panic
main = sorry "help!"
```

produces

```
$ ./A                                
A: A: sorry! (unimplemented feature or known bug)
  (GHC version 7.0.2 for x86_64-unknown-linux):
    help!
```

Constructing GHC warnings should work similarly, checking if `-Werror` is set, and you could clean up the API to be quite useful.

Comment: The warning functions in GHC-API all require access to the parsed command line flags of GHC, so that looks fairly hairy, but I found a TH function `report` which seems to do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

To emit warnings from Template Haskell splices, 
you can use `reportWarning :: String -> Q ()`.

It already includes the location (line and column).
You can implement your `todo` function simply by:

```
todo :: Q Exp
todo = do
  reportWarning "TODO"
  [| undefined |]
```

### Further information

@hammar's answer indicates the function `report`.  It has been deprecated since GHC 7.6 (2012) and will possibly be removed from the API in the near future.
(However, `report` is still available
[on GHC 7.10](https://git.haskell.org/ghc.git/blob/97e7c293abbde5223d2bf0516f8969bdd1a9a7a2:/libraries/template-haskell/Language/Haskell/TH/Syntax.hs)
and
[on GHC master branch](https://git.haskell.org/ghc.git/blob/be92c288839e0bfcf0b15e3bb4136d60f8ef2575:/libraries/template-haskell/Language/Haskell/TH/Syntax.hs)
as of 2015.)

Use `reportError` to report an error and carry on with the `Q` computation
(ultimately failing compilation anyway).

Use `fail` to stop with an error (GHC ≤ 7.10).  That might
[not apply on GHC 8.0](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Status/GHC-8.0.1).